# compiling nginx shell fails from salt provisioner

Tags: shell-script, nginx, vagrant

I have a salt provisioner that is calling a shell script to compile Nginx with a few modules that are needed. This is the call to the script in the `.sls`:

```
nginx:
#  pkg.installed:
#    - name: nginx
  file.directory:
    - name: /src/
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
  cmd.run:
    - name: /srv/salt/config/nginx/compiler.sh | bash
    - cwd: /
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx-compiler-base
```

So it's `/srv/salt/config/nginx/compiler.sh | bash` that is run which does start.  The script run is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ../../../../
cd /src/

nginxVersion="1.5.5" # set the value here from nginx website
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$nginxVersion.tar.gz
tar -xzf nginx-$nginxVersion.tar.gz
#rm nginx # removes the soft link
ln -sf nginx-$nginxVersion nginx

cd nginx

    ./configure --with-http_auth_request_module \
    --with-http_gzip_static_module        \
    --with-http_stub_status_module        \
    --with-http_ssl_module                \
    --with-pcre                           \
    --with-file-aio                       \
    --with-http_realip_module             \
    --without-http_scgi_module            \
    --without-http_uwsgi_module           \
    --without-http_fastcgi_module

make
make install
```

Which does get to the untaring part. After which I get this as the output and failed message:

[image]

If I `ssh` into the server, then `su`, I can run each line in the script and it works.  I'm unsure why it's failing when the provisioner is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it seems that the cause was that I was using `| bash` when I was calling the script. In other words `name: /srv/salt/config/nginx/compiler.sh | bash` should have been `name: /srv/salt/config/nginx/compiler.sh` and so the salt `.sls` should have been:

```
# Set Nginx to run in levels 2345.
nginx:
  file.directory:
    - name: /src/
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
  cmd.run:
    - name: /srv/salt/config/nginx/compiler.sh
    - cwd: /
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx-compiler-base
```

and then the file, which I turned to:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /src

nginxVersion="1.5.7" # set the value here from nginx website
wget -N http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$nginxVersion.tar.gz
tar -xzf nginx-$nginxVersion.tar.gz
ln -sf nginx-$nginxVersion nginx

cd /src/nginx

#mkdir /tmp/nginx-modules
#cd /tmp/nginx-modules
#wget https://github.com/agentzh/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/v0.19.tar.gz
#tar -xzvf v0.19.tar.gz 

./configure --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_realip_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_uwsgi_module

#\
#--add-module=/tmp/nginx-modules/headers-more-nginx-module-0.19 \

make
make install
```

ran and it installed as hoped.  Hope this saves someone some time.